# In Outlook how do I schedule a recurring meeting for every Thursday and every other Tuesday?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook I can use the recurring meetings feature to make one meeting series that occurs every Tuesday and Thursday, for example. But I need it to be every Thursday, but only every second Tuesday. Is it possible to do that with a single recurring meeting?

The main reason I'm hoping for one recurring meeting is so that the meeting chat in Teams is a single chat, rather than separate chats for the Tuesday meetings and the Thursday meetings.

Comment: schedule as two meetings

Comment: Hm. That doesn't quite meet the goals I mentioned. I want the same Teams chat for both meetings. Would I get that if I scheduled them separately?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do that with a single recurring meeting?

With Outlook most current version, there is no ability to do this. Such a request has come forward at Microsoft MVP sessions in Redmond, but nothing has happened as a result of the request.

It may be possible to code a solution but that would be fairly complicated.

Easy way:  Make a meeting appointment and save it.

Then in the Outlook view of calendars, click on the meeting,  press Ctrl-C to copy it, move to the next time, paste it, next time, paste it, and so on.

I do this routinely as the fastest way to create a calendar of meetings that are not strictly recurring.  Works fine.

Comment: Agree with John, there's nothing more convenient than manually scheduling the meetings you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give up the search.

Comment: Your workaround will meet some people's needs, but would it meet mine? Would the Teams chat be the same one for all copies of the meeting?

Comment: I am not certain about Teams, but the method I posted makes true Outlook appointments so it should work.